# How to bind() on TCP client side in rust/tokio?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a need to make sure the client side of the TCP connection goes through a particular (IP) interface. The standard way would be to `bind()` the socket to the `IP:0`, before the `connect()`.

I started looking at `tokio::net::TcpStream::connect()` and friends, which doesn't seem to have a way to do this. I took a step back and looked at `std::net::TcpStream`, which doesn't have it either.

Am I missing something, or do I need to go through some lower level APIs?

Comment: Check the `socket2` crate - with it you can bind() the socket before connect()

Comment: Thanks Svetlin for the pointer. socket2::Socket should certainly work IIUC, this method is available only for the non-async users. I recently ported our system to use async. Is there a way to do this with async?

Comment: Just for my understanding, the non-async sequence would be: socket2::Socket::bind() -> socket2::Socket::connect() -> socket2::Socket::into_tcp_stream(). At this point, one could do a tokio::net::TcpStream::from_std() to move to the async world. But the connect() above is going to be non-async/blocking.   Does this sound right?

Comment: I guess you can do non-blocking connect/bind (by doing socket.set_nonblocking(true)?; first) but then you'll have to handle the complexity in your code.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar: make the socket non-blocking + `tokio::timer::delay_for().await` in a retry loop.

Comment: Answer updated for Tokio 1.x and 0.3

Answer (score 3):

In Tokio version 1.x and 0.3, you can do this through the [`TcpSocket`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1/tokio/net/struct.TcpSocket.html) type using its [`bind`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1/tokio/net/struct.TcpSocket.html#method.bind) method.

```
use std::io::Result;
use tokio::net::{TcpSocket, TcpStream};

async fn connect_bind(bind: SockAddr, connect: SockAddr) -> Result<TcpStream> {
    let socket = TcpSocket::new_v4()?;
    socket.bind(bind)?;

    socket.connect(connect).await
}
```

---

**Old answer for Tokio 0.2**

The best way of doing this at the moment is indeed to use `socket2` to create the socket and convert it into a Tokio `TcpStream`. In order to correctly handle the fact that the connection step will be blocking with this approach, you can use [`tokio::task::spawn_blocking`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html).

```rs
use std::io::Result;

use tokio::task::spawn_blocking;
use tokio::net::TcpStream;

use socket2::{Socket, SockAddr, Domain, Type};

async fn connect_bind(bind: SockAddr, connect: SockAddr) -> Result<TcpStream> {
    spawn_blocking(move || {
        let socket = Socket::new(Domain::ipv4(), Type::stream(), None)?;
        socket.bind(&bind)?;
        socket.connect(&connect)?;
        TcpStream::from_std(socket.into_tcp_stream())
    }).await?
}
```

Using `spawn_blocking` like this is rather common — this is how Tokio implements file system operations.